# Dynamic columns in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, staggeredgridlayout

i want to create a grid in android wherein suppose

1. [if i pass an arraylist with 5 elements first row should have 3 columns and next row should have 2 columns with centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmUWu.png)
2. if i pass an arraylist with 6 elements first row should have 3 columns and next row should have 3 columns
3. [if i pass an arraylist with 7 elements first row should have 3 columns, next row should have 3 columns and next row should have 1 column with centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KmA7.png)

Comment: If you are using a GridView then did you try setting column to 3 in your xml ?

Comment: @pooja nopes it does not work, it displays 3 in first column and 2 in second but not in center

Comment: ok now got the proper point of your question after seeing your image

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you using [`FlexBoxLayout`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). It is similar to CSS's `FlexBox` and fits exactly your needs.

Just add deppendency to Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.2.3'
}
```

Put the layout in .xml file:

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout/>
```

and add view's children dynamically:

```
flexBox.addView(child);
```